# Check if cell is empty in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have my table where I can add new rows by simply clicking "Add" button (solution found on SO). What I want is detecting if new row added this way has any empty cells in order to disable "Save" button under  the whole table so that user cannot save such changes to DB.

Any ideas?

Comment: The data binding to ng-grid is updated when you add new rows. Just check the data to see if any field is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the handy validation of AngularJS?

Define your cellTemplates like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><input type="text" required ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\"></div>'
    }, {
        field: 'age',
        displayName: 'Age',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><input type="text" required ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\"></div>'
    }]
};
```

Note the `required` attribute in the inputs.

Then put the whole grid in a form and give the **SAVE** button a `ng-disabled` directive.

```
<button ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

Here is a minimalistic [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WJb3GBT5UTOZWeT21fId?p=preview)

Comment: It's almost a solution to my problem, but I use excel-like editing so that I would like to see inputs only when I double click a single cell.

Comment: Look at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EcstZjdHDMwtvjmMWuLk?p=preview I changed the cellTemplate to the editableCellTemplate, added a ng-change event that checks if another column field is empty and set the form to invalid if something isn't good. This is very hackerish and doesn't fully work as expected. For example the input fields don't switch back to the displayTemplate. But it kind'a works. Since its very humid in Germany today and I leave work for today I'll leave it up to you or any other helpful person to find our more. Keep me informed on how you solved this. Best I could do:-\